# Disable boostrap toggle collapse for one class and enable it for another

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a boostrap collapse button that looks like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#<?php echo $row['pid']; ?>">View more info</button>
    <div id="<?php echo $row['pid']; ?>" class="collapse">
        <?php
        //php code that display more info goes here
        }
        echo '</div>';
  ?>
```

when user click this button, more information about the picture will be revealed. Because each picture has unique information, the div id and data-target of this button has to be the id of the picture in the database, otherwise no accurate information can be displayed.
However, I also have a like button, when a user clicked it, he will "liked" the picture, and it goes like this :

```
<button type="button" class="like" id="<?php echo $row['pid']; ?>">Like <span><?php echo likes($row['pid']); ?></span></button>
```

the id of the like button also has to be identical to the id of the picture in the database, because in the javascript code I use this id to know which picture's like button is being clicked, and then I can add the number of likes for that picture.

The problem is, both the like button and the collapse button have the same id(the id of the picture). When I clicked the collapse button, instead of showing more information about the picture, the number of likes is being hidden.  I tried to disabled boostrap collapse based on classes by the following code :

```
<script>

    $('.like').bootstrapToggle('off');
   $('.collapse').bootstrapToggle('on');

</script>
```

but it's not working. If I delete the "like" button everything will work smoothly, but after adding the like button, the collapse button would hide the like button when it's clicked. What can I do to not the the collapse button interfere with the likes button?

Comment: Basically, you can't have two elements with the same ID in single HTML document. You can use for example data attributes for like button (data-id instead of id, then you can also easily read this value in JavaScript)

Comment: can you be more specific about how to use data-id? I need to associate each like button with the picture(so that I will know which user likes which picture, and count the number of likes)and each picture can only be "identified" by their id on the database

Comment: I can't help you without seeing the code where you are sending data to your database (you are probably using AJAX?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is an example where you use the same id :

> ABCD1234

on both elements but on the like button you apply it as a data attribute. When the button is clicked, you retrieve the id via the data attribute and then use it as a selector to update the like count on the appropriate matching collapsed content based on that id.

**HTML**

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#ABCD1234" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
  Button with data-target
</button>
<div class="collapse" id="ABCD1234">
  <div class="well">
    <span>100</span> likes
  </div>
</div>

<br>
<button type="button" class="like" data-id="ABCD1234">Like <span>ABCD1234</span></button>
```

**JS**

```
$('.like').click(function(){
  var thisID = '#' + $(this).data('id');
  var $count = $('span', thisID);
  var number = parseInt($count.text());
  $count.text(number+1);
});
```

https://codepen.io/partypete25/pen/XgqBZX

Comment: When user clicked the like button, I use AJAX to change the number of likes, for example, if there are 10 likes, when a user clicked the button, AJAX will change it to 11. Originally(when using id instead of data-id), I have var postid = $(this).data('id'), and in the ajax response I use: 
  success:function(data){ $('a#'+postid).html(data); } Now, if i'm using data-id instead of id, what should I use in the ajax-response? I tried $('a[data-id='+postid']').html(data);
$('a#'+"[data-id=postid"]).text(data);  etc, but none of them work, only creating more errors

Comment: Almost got it. It's: $('a[data-id="'+postid+'"]').html(data);